# Errors with Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to work with Tensorflow Object Detection API as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md).

I did exactly what is described there, but I got the following errors:

```
python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py

..EE...
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_faster_rcnn_resnet_v1_models_from_config (__main__.ModelBuilderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 258, in test_create_faster_rcnn_resnet_v1_models_from_config
    for extractor_type, extractor_class in FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_MAPS.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_rfcn_resnet_v1_model_from_config (__main__.ModelBuilderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 448, in test_create_rfcn_resnet_v1_model_from_config
    for extractor_type, extractor_class in FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_MAPS.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.019s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Please help me to understand what's wrong there, many thanks!

Comment: Just found out that it's a non-supported method call in Python3, changed to "items()".

Answer (score 4):

As you are in python3, use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems()

iteritems() does not exist in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `diction.items()` function. An example would be:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7}
print ("Value : %s" %  dict.items())
```

**Output:**

```
Value : dict_items([('Name', 'Zara'), ('Age', 7)])
```